# Can you display different map in a drawn polygon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

Is it possible in leaflet.js to draw a polygon on a map with one WMS and in this polygon display different WMS? (For example I want the user to be able to view a map with dark theme and than draw shapes on said map and in this shapes map would change to light theme.)

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#tileimage-display

Comment: I've had good results drawing masked tile layers with [leaflet-boundary-canvas](https://github.com/aparshin/leaflet-boundary-canvas)